# Add a bunch of `0x` before numbers in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2

I want to add `0x` before every number and `,` after every number. The data is as following

Before:

```
00 01 01 7f 00 00 00 00    00 00 04 0a 00 00 00 00
00 00 01 02 2d 00 c0 00    00 c0 01 00 03 03 03 03
00 00 44 53 50 33 5f 30    30 33 00 00 00 00 04 05
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00
```

After:

```
0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x7f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, ...
```

How can do that in `Sublime Text` efficiently?

Comment: Generally I'd say do a regex replace `\s+` to `, 0x`, but since I don't know Sublime, I'mm leave it to someone else to explain how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do the following.

1. `Ctrl + H` to launch Find & Replace
2. Enable Regex mode by clicking the small button that looks like `.*` on the left
3. Find What : `(\w\w)`. That will match two alpha numeric characters.
4. Replace With: `0x$1,`. Basically, this means prefix with `0x`, use the back reference (`$1`) to print original and finally add `,` at the end.
5. Hit replace or replace all.

Hope that helps!